# views stops showing anytime i inject ui.bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After injecting ui.bootstrap into my module the application is loading a blank page without throwing any errors.

```
angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap'])
```

If i remove the injection the page loads fine.

```
 angular.module('app')
```

I have all the necessary includes

```
<script src="assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/ui-router.js"></script>
```

[image: with ui.bootstrap injected]

[image: without ui.bootstrap]

when angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap']) ui.bootsrap is injected this is what i get 
when angular.module('app') is not injected it works well

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the require JS file in your page. After `angular-animate.js` (before `ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js`), insert this tag

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Imm -- Please observe your console, and update your question with the errors if there are any.